# How do you use type=inline in TYPO3 to create repeating fields?

Tags: php, typo3, fluid, typo3-9.x

In TYPO3 I want to make an element that allows the user to create multiple sub-blocks within it.
For example:

```
Create New +
|
|- Sub Block
|  |- Assets
|  |- Text Field
|
|- Sub Block
|  |- Assets
|  |- Text Field
```

From what I understand this is done using [type='inline'](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/master/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/Inline.html)

However the documentation assumes you know all previous steps of the process, and I have found no tutorials on this kind of element.

Comment: First of all you need to create an extension. If you never did this before check "extension-builder" (composer require friendsoftypo3/extension-builder). The bootstrap_package (https://github.com/benjaminkott/bootstrap_package) is a very good starting point for creating custom content elements. There are also excamples for IRRE like accordion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a new content element with a 1:n relation to a new record (not content element), you have to add a new record and a new property of tt_content describing the relation between tt_content and your record.

1. Add a new table for your new record
2. Add TCA for your new record
3. Allow record to be added in default pages
4. Extend table tt_content
5. Add TCA for your new content element

As a basic example, I create a new record "my_list_item" and a new content element "my_list":

Add new table for your new record (ext_tables.sql):

```
CREATE TABLE tx_myext_domain_model_mylistitem (

    parent_uid int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    parent_table varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
    title varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL

);
```

Describe new record in TCA (Configuration/TCA/tx_myext_domain_model_mylistitem.php

```
<?php
return [
    'ctrl' => [
        'title' => 'Label',
        'label' => 'title',
        'tstamp' => 'tstamp',
        'crdate' => 'crdate',
        'cruser_id' => 'cruser_id',
        'sortby' => 'sorting',
        'versioningWS' => true,
        'languageField' => 'sys_language_uid',
        'transOrigPointerField' => 'l10n_parent',
        'transOrigDiffSourceField' => 'l10n_diffsource',
        'delete' => 'deleted',
        'hideTable' => true,
        'enablecolumns' => [
            'disabled' => 'hidden',
        ],
        'searchFields' => 'title',
    ],
    'interface' => [
        'showRecordFieldList' => 'sys_language_uid, l10n_parent, l10n_diffsource, hidden, title',
    ],
    'columns' => [
        'sys_language_uid' => [
            'exclude' => true,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.language',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'select',
                'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
                'special' => 'languages',
                'items' => [
                    [
                        'LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.allLanguages',
                        -1,
                        'flags-multiple'
                    ]
                ],
                'default' => 0,
            ],
        ],
        'l10n_parent' => [
            'displayCond' => 'FIELD:sys_language_uid:>:0',
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.l18n_parent',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'select',
                'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
                'default' => 0,
                'items' => [
                    ['', 0],
                ],
                'foreign_table' => 'tx_myext_domain_model_mylistitem',
                'foreign_table_where' => 'AND {#tx_myext_domain_model_mylistitem}.{#pid}=###CURRENT_PID### AND {#tx_myext_domain_model_mylistitem}.{#sys_language_uid} IN (-1,0)',
            ],
        ],
        'l10n_diffsource' => [
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'passthrough',
            ],
        ],
        't3ver_label' => [
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.versionLabel',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'input',
                'size' => 30,
                'max' => 255,
            ],
        ],
        'hidden' => [
            'exclude' => true,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.visible',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'check',
                'renderType' => 'checkboxToggle',
                'items' => [
                    [
                        0 => '',
                        1 => '',
                        'invertStateDisplay' => true
                    ]
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'title' => [
            'exclude' => true,
            'label' => 'Your header label',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'input',
                'size' => 30,
                'eval' => 'trim,required'
            ],
        ],
        'parent_uid' => [
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'select',
                'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
                'items' => [
                    [
                        '',
                        0,
                    ],
                ],
                'default' => 0,
                'foreign_table' => 'tt_content',
                'foreign_table_where' => 'AND tt_content.pid=###CURRENT_PID### AND tt_content.sys_language_uid IN (-1, ###REC_FIELD_sys_language_uid###)',
            ],
        ],
        'parent_table' => [
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'passthrough',
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'types' => [
        '1' => ['showitem' =>
            '--div--;LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/Form/locallang_tabs.xlf:general, title, bodytext, --div--;LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/Form/locallang_tabs.xlf:language, sys_language_uid, l10n_parent, l10n_diffsource, --div--;LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/Form/locallang_tabs.xlf:access, hidden'
        ],
    ],
];
```

Allow record on pages (ext_tables.php):

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::allowTableOnStandardPages('tx_myext_domain_model_mylistitem');
```

Describe the TCA of the new record with the relation to itself (Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php)

```
$myListItemTca = [
    'tx_myext_mylist' => [
        'exclude' => true,
        'label' => 'Field label',
        'config' => [
            'appearance' => [
                'collapseAll' => '1',
                'enabledControls' => [
                    'dragdrop' => '1',
                ],
                'levelLinksPosition' => 'bottom',
                'useSortable' => '1',
            ],
            'foreign_field' => 'parent_uid',
            'foreign_table' => 'tx_myext_domain_model_mylistitem',
            'foreign_table_field' => 'parent_table',
            'maxitems' => '20',
            'minitems' => '1',
            'type' => 'inline',
        ],
    ],
];

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns(
    'tt_content',
    $myListItemTca
);
```

Extend tt_content (ext_tables.sql)

```
CREATE TABLE tt_content (
    tx_myext_mylist int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
);
```

Add a new content element (Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php):

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['palettes']['mylist'] = array(
    'showitem' =>
        'tx_myext_mylist; Label',
    'canNotCollapse' => 1
);

$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['mylist'] = array(
    'showitem' => '
        --div--;LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/Form/locallang_tabs.xlf:general,
            --palette--;;general,
            --palette--;;headers,
            --palette--;Label;mylist,
    ',
);

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTcaSelectItem(
    'tt_content',
    'CType',
    [
        'Title',
        'mylist',
    ],
    'textmedia',
    'after'
);
```

This is just a basic example, reduced and replaced names from a working example I made a few weeks ago. Should I missed something, comment.

BTW: This is the same way which mask / mask exports handles repeatable elements. So of course you can also use mask export and clean the generated code for your own purpose (the code is of mask export is good and usable, but there is a bit overhead, as it must be more generic)

Comment: This is really helpful, however it gives an error for `parent_uid` and `parent_table` in tt_content?

Comment: I forgot the TCA of the record itself and to allow this record on default pages. Updated my answer. Should work now...

Comment: Ok, cool. I can add the element now but the repeater part has a red exclamation, and if you try clicking 'Create New' it gives a Error 500 internal server error?

Comment: What does the log file say? Note: This is a basic code example. To have a füll working solution, you can use mask. The most Important code segment is the relation mapping...

Comment: I copied the custom record php from mask_export to my ext and substituted your example names from above, but it's now giving an exception for `'SELECT uid` about parent_uid and parent_table, and says unknown column.

Comment: Why mix up this example with mask export? You can use mask OR you can build it on your own, following this example. In your former comment, you mentioned an error. Can you access the error log and show, what is missing there?

Comment: Ok, if I use exactly as you say above the error log says `No columns definition in TCA table tx_myext_domain_model_mylistitem`

Comment: I guess, your TCA of "mylistitem" was incomplete. I added only the three new fields in the code above. See now the full TCA, build on T3 10.

Comment: Yeah, using that gives me the same error I was having before when using mask_export to fill in the gaps. (I am testing on T3 9.5 If that makes a difference)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the extensions [`mask`](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/mask/) and [`mask_export`](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/mask_export/) to generate an extension for your kind of content element.

They handle everything for you from table enhancement to table declaration, with all code in mySQL and PHP (including TCA, getter/setter, ...).

---

If you want to do it by your own have a look in the documentation:

1. [How to define own content elements](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/10.4/en-us/ApiOverview/ContentElements/Index.html)
2. [How to define TCA inline elments](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/master/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/Inline.html)

Comment: If I used mask_export and deconstructed the output, would this show me how to do it on my own? Or is the output more complicated than what you would do if you were to make the same thing from scratch?

Comment: `mask_export` will give you a full extension with all necessary code. of course you can use that code as an example for your extension. Be aware you need some declarations which need to match (e.g. DB fieldname - getter/setter - TCA) and these usages sometimes have different spellings (camelCase <-> underscore_usage)